# How to get the class name on the img of this td's siblings?

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors

http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/quzyx

Hi, basically the selector `request`-row on specific td's which hit a click event in jQuery.

I'm able to get the number associated to the `data-message-id` on the tr, however I'm having trouble finding the right way to target the name of the class which is on the image in the first td.

---

The HTML Markup:

```
<table>
<tr data-message-id="101010">
    <td class="table-icon request-row">
        <img class="accepted-icon" src="http://leongaban.com/_projects/whoat/_HTML/img/icon-orange-tick.png" alt="Accepted"/>
    </td>
    <td class="data-name request-row">
        Name
    </td>
    <td class="data-career request-row">
        Title
    </td>
    <td class="data-company request-row">
        Company
    </td>
    <td>Some image goes here<!--Not clickable--></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My jQuery

```
$(".request-row").unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
    alert('clicked .request-row');

    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var id = $tr.data('message-id');
    msg_id_incoming = id;
    var userType = $tr.data('type');

    // if accepted then change up the content displayed...
    //var $status = $(this).parent.children('img').attr('class');
    var $status = $(this).siblings('img').attr('class');  
    alert($status);

});
```

---

How would you re-write the code under the `// if accepted then change up the content displayed...` comment, to get the class name that is on the image when a td with the class name `request-row` is clicked?

My Codepen: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/quzyx

Comment: could you simply add another class that would always be there and then check if other class exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be:

```
$(this).siblings('td.table-icon').find('img').attr('class');
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/pz8vk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var $status = $(this).siblings().first().children('img').attr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your image is in a td, therefor not a silbling of `this`, you need to select the sibling containing the image then get the image:

```
$(this).siblings('td:has(img)').children('img').attr('class')
```